# Missing figures in "List of figures"

Tags: floats

After using continued float, the output figures are as I desired but they do not appear in the list of figures. Here is the sample code for the part.

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{figure}{2}
\begin{figure}[!htpb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{figure1.1}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{figure1.2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{figure1.3}}
    \caption[]{Figure caption}
    \label{xyz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've disabled the list of figures-entry with the empty brackets in

```
\caption[]{Figure caption}
```

use

```
\caption{Figure caption}
```

instead.